# Detectar tecla enter con jquery

Tags: jquery

Buenas tardes tengo la siguiente duda, como veran necesito que cuando se presione la tecla enter ejectue una funcion que ya tengo creada.

Si detecta la tecla y entra a la funcion que tengo creada porque muestra las alertas que pongo dentro de ella pero el problema es que el codigo ajax que tengo dentro de esa funcion no se ejecuta por que esta pasando esto??

Este es el codigo que estoy usando

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
      $("#dato").keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
          obtenerDatos();
        }
      });
});

function obtenerDatos()
{
    var valor = $("#dato").val();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST', 
      url:  'getDatos.php',
      data: "valor=" + valor,
      success: function(response){
            $("#wrap").html(response);
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: ¿no se ejecuta el keypress o no te funciona el Ajax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te recomiendo la siguiente modificación:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dato").keypress(function(e) {
        //no recuerdo la fuente pero lo recomiendan para
        //mayor compatibilidad entre navegadores.
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if(code==13){
            obtenerDatos();
        }
    });
});

function obtenerDatos() { var valor = $("#dato").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST', 
      url:  'getDatos.php',
      data: "valor=" + valor,
      success: function(response){
            $("#wrap").html(response);
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: No funciona, ya lo cambie a como me lo aconsejaste y sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Debes de asegurarte de incluir la biblioteca de JQuery de manera correcta en la sección del encabezado. Otra cosa que puedes probar es mostrar las herramientas de depuración, que en la mayoría de los navegadores es F12. Aca te dejo la muestra del código funcionando https://jsfiddle.net/e9znuf2d/2/

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo que faltaría es evitar que se dispare el evento asociado al ENTER, usando preventDefault()

```
  $("#dato").keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      obtenerDatos();
    }
  });
```

lala

Answer (score 0):

Encontré una solución y es la que me ha funcionado, verán cuando presionaba enter pasaba que se volvía a recargar la pagina lo que necesitaba es que no se volviera a recargar la pagina cuando presionara el enter por lo que investigando encontré que había que anular el enter en el input de tipo texto

Y modifique mi código así:

$("#dato").keypress(function(e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if(code == 13){
          obtenerDatos();
          return false;
        }
      });